# Whonix Signature verification failure

Tags: tor, anonymity

I've downloaded Whonix images and I have successfully imported the signing key (https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Whonix_Signing_Key). I have also established trust for the said key and verified that by checking in Kleopetra that the key is now listed under Trusted certificates.
I am however, unable to verify integrity of the downloaded images with an error - "could not determine whether this is an S/MIME or an OpenPGP signature - maybe it is not a signature at all?"
Can anyone tell me where I may be going wrong?